# Data type to query local dates and relative datetimes

Tags: sql-server, datetime, timestamp-with-timezone

I need to represent some instant in some place in an Azure SQL database. I need to be able to effectively query whether two events occurred on the same local date, and whether some event in an arbitrary place happened before another event in another arbitrary place.

If I use a `DateTimeOffset`, every time I want to query whether something happened on a local date, I have to cast to `Date`, which probably means I won't be able to use any index on the column.

If I use a `Date` column containing the local date, a `Time` column containing the local time, and an offset column, I need to join them together to get an absolute datetime, which probably mean I won't be able to use any index on the columns.

If I use both all off them, I can have indexes on everything, but my data model doesn't offer guarantees about the coherence between them.

Is there a way to model this data where I can query efficiently both for equality of a local event date (e.g. the event occurred on December 12, 2018, in its local time, regardless of what offset that may have) and query efficiently on the moment in time, while having coherence between them enforced by the data model?

Answer (score 1):

A `datetimeoffset` column will allow you to efficiently query for both equality and range as long as you avoid converting the column value. Rather than casting as date, date range queries involving temporal types that include a time component can be accomplished efficiently with an inclusive start value and exclusive end value.

Below is an example showing both an equality and range search. A clustered index seek is used in both cases.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.DateTimeOffsetExample (
        DateTimeOffsetColumn datetimeoffset NOT NULL
);
CREATE INDEX cdx ON dbo.DateTimeOffsetExample(DateTimeOffsetColumn);
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.DateTimeOffsetExample(DateTimeOffsetColumn)
VALUES
    --Central Standard Time
      ('2018-12-14 23:00:00.00000000 -06:00')
    , ('2018-12-15 07:00:00.00000000 -06:00')      
    , ('2018-12-15 12:00:00.00000000 -06:00')
    , ('2018-12-15 19:00:00.00000000 -06:00')
    , ('2018-12-15 22:00:00.00000000 -06:00')
    , ('2018-12-15 23:00:00.00000000 -06:00')
    , ('2018-12-16 00:00:00.00000000 -06:00')
    --Eastern Standard Time
    , ('2018-12-15 00:00:00.00000000 -05:00')
    , ('2018-12-15 08:00:00.00000000 -05:00')      
    , ('2018-12-15 13:00:00.00000000 -05:00')
    , ('2018-12-15 20:00:00.00000000 -05:00')
    , ('2018-12-15 23:00:00.00000000 -05:00')
    , ('2018-12-16 00:00:00.00000000 -05:00')
    , ('2018-12-16 01:00:00.00000000 -05:00')
    --Central European Standard Time
    , ('2018-12-15 06:00:00.00000000 +01:00')
    , ('2018-12-15 14:00:00.00000000 +01:00')
    , ('2018-12-15 19:00:00.00000000 +01:00')
    , ('2018-12-16 02:00:00.00000000 +01:00')
    , ('2018-12-16 05:00:00.00000000 +01:00')
    , ('2018-12-16 06:00:00.00000000 +01:00')
    , ('2018-12-16 07:00:00.00000000 +01:00')
    --SE Asia Standard Time
    , ('2018-12-15 12:00:00.00000000 +07:00')
    , ('2018-12-15 20:00:00.00000000 +07:00')
    , ('2018-12-16 01:00:00.00000000 +07:00')
    , ('2018-12-16 08:00:00.00000000 +07:00')
    , ('2018-12-16 11:00:00.00000000 +07:00')
    , ('2018-12-16 12:00:00.00000000 +07:00')
    , ('2018-12-16 13:00:00.00000000 +07:00');
GO
```

Equality:

```
--equality (clustered index seek using equality predicate)
DECLARE @LocalTime datetimeoffset = '2018-12-15 00:00:00.00000000 -05:00';
SELECT *
FROM dbo.DateTimeOffsetExample
WHERE DateTimeOffsetColumn = @LocalTime;

+------------------------------------+
|        DateTimeOffsetColumn        |
+------------------------------------+
| 2018-12-14 23:00:00.0000000 -06:00 |
| 2018-12-15 00:00:00.0000000 -05:00 |
| 2018-12-15 06:00:00.0000000 +01:00 |
| 2018-12-15 12:00:00.0000000 +07:00 |
+------------------------------------+
```

Range query for single date:

```
--range (clustered index seek using range predicate)
DECLARE
      @LocalTimeStart datetimeoffset = '2018-12-15 00:00:00.00000000 -05:00'
    , @LocalTimeEnd datetimeoffset = '2018-12-16 00:00:00.00000000 -05:00';
SELECT *
FROM dbo.DateTimeOffsetExample
WHERE DateTimeOffsetColumn >= @LocalTimeStart
    AND DateTimeOffsetColumn < @LocalTimeEnd;

+------------------------------------+
|        DateTimeOffsetColumn        |
+------------------------------------+
| 2018-12-14 23:00:00.0000000 -06:00 |
| 2018-12-15 00:00:00.0000000 -05:00 |
| 2018-12-15 06:00:00.0000000 +01:00 |
| 2018-12-15 12:00:00.0000000 +07:00 |
| 2018-12-15 07:00:00.0000000 -06:00 |
| 2018-12-15 08:00:00.0000000 -05:00 |
| 2018-12-15 14:00:00.0000000 +01:00 |
| 2018-12-15 20:00:00.0000000 +07:00 |
| 2018-12-15 12:00:00.0000000 -06:00 |
| 2018-12-15 13:00:00.0000000 -05:00 |
| 2018-12-15 19:00:00.0000000 +01:00 |
| 2018-12-16 01:00:00.0000000 +07:00 |
| 2018-12-15 19:00:00.0000000 -06:00 |
| 2018-12-15 20:00:00.0000000 -05:00 |
| 2018-12-16 02:00:00.0000000 +01:00 |
| 2018-12-16 08:00:00.0000000 +07:00 |
| 2018-12-15 22:00:00.0000000 -06:00 |
| 2018-12-15 23:00:00.0000000 -05:00 |
| 2018-12-16 05:00:00.0000000 +01:00 |
| 2018-12-16 11:00:00.0000000 +07:00 |
+------------------------------------+
```

Comment: How would you perform the query "on december 15 2018 local time"?

Comment: Since my local time is `-06:00`, I would specify `DateTimeOffsetColumn >=  '2018-12-15 00:00:00.00000000 -06:00' AND DateTimeOffsetColumn <  '2018-12-16 00:00:00.00000000 -06:00'`.

Comment: That selects all records where *your* local date is December 15, not nessecarily the records local date, right?

Comment: @Martijn, correct. The date of the selected rows may be different because it's not my local date. You can such results in my answer, where the 3 different dates are returned for the same (Eastern Standard Time) date.

Comment: I'm looking to find all events on the wall-time date from the perspective of the event though: if I'm looking for events that occurred on December 15, 2018, and the event occurred on 2018-12-15 01:00 +40:00 I still want to find it.